# Kotlin class hierarchy and (co)variance

Tags: kotlin, generics, covariance

In my setup, I'm trying to have an interface `Table` that inherits from `Map` (because it will mostly be used as a wrapper around the map). Two classes inherit from `Table` - local and global. The global one will have a mutable map, and the local one will have a map of only local entries.

```kotlin
// entries
sealed class Entry {
    class EntryLocal : Entry
    class EntryGlobal : Entry
}

interface Table : Map<String, Entry> {
    fun getRecursive(key: String): Entry?   
}

class GlobalTable(val map:MutableMap<String, Entry>) : Table, Map<String, Entry> by map {
    override fun getRecursive(key: String) = this[key]

    ...
}

class LocalTable(
    private val parent: Table,
    val map: Map<String, EntryLocal>
) : Table, Map<String, EntryLocal> { // gives error
    override fun getRecursive(key: String): Entry? = map[key] ?: parent.getRecursive(key)

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Type parameter V of 'Map' has inconsistent values: Entry, EntryVar
```

Why is that? Doesn't `Map<String, EntryLocal>` inherit from `Map<String, Entry>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right the value type of `Map` is covariant and so a `Map<String, EntryLocal>` is a `Map<String, Entry>`.

However, that's not your problem here. The problem is that `LocalTable` inherits from both `Map<String, EntryLocal>` (directly) and `Map<String, Entry>` (via `Table`) so it's not clear what the value type should be in `LocalTable`.

In other words, what's the return type of `LocalTable.get`? Is it `Entry` or `EntryLocal`?

Here's the problem in a nutshell:

```
interface M<T> {}
interface A : M<String> {}
interface B : M<Object> {}
class C : A, B {}
```

You'll get the same error saying that parameter `T` of `M` has inconsistent values. Even though `String` is an `Object`, Kotlin won't assume that the type parameter `T` of the base class `M` should therefore be `String` (or `Object`).

Comment: Thank you! I wish this was supported - I don't see why it would cause trouble for the compiler. Also, does the above compile? I thought Kotlin doesn't support multiple inheritance for classes (it would work with interfaces)

Comment: It *also* says "Only one class may appear in a supertype list" in addition to the error you were getting. But you're right, the example would be clearer with interfaces!

Comment: You can make it work by making the type of Table's Key a `T` where `T: Entry`, but you will get stuck at making LocalTable's parent anything but a LocalTable, because otherwise `parent.getRecursive(key)` won't return an EntryLocal.

Comment: That's fine - `LocalTable::getRecursive` returns an entry anyway (because it goes up to parents, which could be a `GlobalTable`